# Unique solutions with given inital value problem for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

For the equation

$$y' = \sqrt{y}, \quad y(0) = a$$

I got the solution $y = \frac{1}{4} (t+a)^2$. How can I determine the values of $a$ for which this IVP has a solution and for what values the solution is unique? $\sqrt{y}$ is continuous on the interval $[0,\infty]$, so are there unique solutions on this interval? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about the [existence and uniqueness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for ODEs?

Comment: So far you know that it exists from $[0,\infty]$. So the question that you're asking is for a different values of $a$ can you find a $t$ such that $y_1(t)=y_2(t)$.  If you can find one then it's not unique within a given interval. It will start being unique when you can't find one. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uniqueness of solutions, it is not enough that the vector field is continuous. For a differential equation $y'=f(y)$, if $f$ is continuous on an open set $U$, then for any $a \in U$ the IVP $y'=f(y), \ y(0)=a$ has *at least one solution* over a sufficiently small time interval $[0,\varepsilon)$. But if $f$ is *Lipschitz* on an open set $U \ni a$, then the IVP $y'=f(y), \ y(0)=a$ has *exactly one solution* over a sufficiently small time interval $[0,\varepsilon)$.

(By the way, all the above statements hold for backward-time solutions as well as for forward-time solutions.)

In your case, $\sqrt{y}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, so at least one solution always *exists* (at least for a small finite time - although in this particular case it turns out to exist for all time); but $\sqrt{y}$ is *not* Lipschitz on any neighbourhood of $0$.

The full answer to your question is:

> > For $a>0$: The solution $y(t)=\frac{1}{4}(t+2\sqrt{a})^2$ is a solution; and it must be the only solution, since $\sqrt{y}$ is locally Lipschitz on $(0,\infty)$ and it is clear that $y(t)$ cannot fall to $0$. ...

[By the way, I think that when you calculated your solution, you incorrectly assumed that the constant of integration is equal to the initial condition $a$. You cannot assume this: to compute the constant of integration $c$ in terms of $a$, you need to use your expression for $y(t)$ in terms of $c$, set $t=0$, and then equate the result to $a$.]

> > ... But for $a=0$: The solution $y(t)=\frac{1}{4}t^2$ is a solution, but it is not the only solution; for, indeed, an even more obvious solution is $y(t)=0$. In fact, for every $r \geq 0$, the function
> >     $$ y_r(t) \ = \ \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} 0 & 0 \leq t \leq r \\ \tfrac{1}{4}(t-r)^2 & t \geq r \end{array} \right. $$
> >     is a solution.

If you want a fun exercise, see if you can prove that for $a=0$, the solutions mentioned above are *all* the solutions.

Comment: The theorem about existence and uniqueness for locally Lipschitz vector fields is the one cited by Mattos in his comment. But I think the wikipedia article is not very good for its formulation of the actual statement and proof. I think [here](https://math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/lec4.pdf) is better. The slightly less famous theorem about existence of at least one solution for continuous vector fields can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem).

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. How do we know that there are multiple solutions when a=0? I am having difficulty seeing that part.

Comment: Well, you first note that your general solution $y(t)=\frac{1}{4}(t+2\sqrt{a})^2$ is just as valid for $a=0$ as it is for any other $a$, but then you also observe that $y(t)=0$ happens to be a valid solution that is different from $y(t)=\frac{1}{4}t^2$. I'm not aware of any general theorem that *guarantees* the existence of more than one solution; but if you observe that the locally Lipschitz condition fails, then there might be more than one solution. In particular: for $y'=f(y)$, if $f(0)=0$ then $y(t)=0$ *must* be a solution. (If $f$ is locally Lipschitz at 0 then it is the only solution.)

Comment: Thanks! How do we know that y(t)=0 is a valid solution different from y(t) = (1/4)*(t^2)? Is this because y(0) = a?

Comment: To clarify, I guess my real question is, if the equation is y(t) = (1/4)*(t^2) and  a is 0, why isn't y(t) = 0 the only solution?

Comment: Also, why do we not have to consider a < 0?

Comment: Okay, it looks like there might be some fundamental misunderstandings. Given a function $f$ and a value $a$, a "solution of the IVP $y'=f(y),y(0)=a$" means a function $y(\cdot)$ with the properties that $y(0)=a$ and for every $t$, $y'(t)=f(y(t))$. [If I don't specify an initial condition "$y(0)=a$", then a "solution of the ODE $y'=f(y)$" means any function $y(\cdot)$ with the property that for every $t$, $y'(t)=f(y(t))$.]

Comment: So considering $f=\sqrt{\ \ \ }$ and $a=0$: The function $y \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $y(t)=\frac{1}{4}t^2$ is a solution of the IVP $y'=\sqrt{y},y(0)=0$, because $y(0)=\frac{1}{4}.0^2=0$, and $y'(t)=\frac{1}{2}t=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}t^2}=\sqrt{y(t)}$ for all $t\in [0,\infty)$. But the function $y \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $y(t)=0 \ \forall \, t$ is a *different* function, and yet it *also* has the properties that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(t)=0=\sqrt{0}=\sqrt{y(t)}$ for all $t$. So it is another solution of the same IVP.

Comment: We cannot consider an initial condition $a<0$ because the $\sqrt{\ \ \ }$ function is only defined on nonnegative values. So the ODE $y'=\sqrt{y}$ only makes sense on the phase space $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you!! This is helpful. Where does r come from in the answer?

Comment: It is possible to verify [try to prove this yourself!] that given any positive number - let's call it $r$ - the function $y\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $y(t)=0$ for $t\leq r$ and $y(t)=\frac{1}{4}(t-r)^2$ for $t>r$ is a solution of the IVP $y'=\sqrt{y},y(0)=0$. (This solution "waits at $0$ for time $r$, and then moves away".) If there are still things you're unclear about, can I suggest that (for your best benefit) you print out this MathSE page and have a discussion with a professor who can speak to you face-to-face.